# How to sorted Parent Page in WP-admin

Tags: pages, admin-menu

I have a question. I want to sort pages by title in Page attributes - Parent page in post in WP-admin ??
Any ideas on how to do this?
[image]

Comment: To do this in the block editor will need you to make JS based code changes, but this might be something that GB could integrate if you raise a bug report on the Gutenberg GitHub

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order that your pages are displayed when using a default menu by using the Order field of the Page Attributes module.

Let’s say you have three pages: About, Photos, Contact

If you wanted About to appear first, you’d need to do the following:

1. Go to Site → Pages in your dashboard
2. Find the page About and click the title.
3. Locate the Page Attributes module to the right of the editor.
4. Put the number 1 in the box for Order. This tells WordPress to
   display this page first on your site.
5. Click the Update button.

Repeat the process for your other pages, but use higher numbers for the Order field: 2, 3, etc. This tells WordPress to display these pages second and third on your blog.